# Не подключается к php websocket-у при запуске демона

Tags: php, linux, websocket, workerman

Использую библиотеку [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman).
При тестировании запускал вебсокет сервер чата путем
/opt/php70/bin/php /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/backend/index.php
 start

Но он вебсокет сервер падает, решил запустить как демона, командой

/opt/php70/bin/php /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/backend/index.php
 start -d

О такой команде говорит [**документация**](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman)

При запуске демона - клиент не может подключиться к серверу.

В **netstat -natp**

tcp   0   0   95.216.77.147:81   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   16907/WorkerMan: ma

upd. сменил порт с 81 на другой, учитывая советы не занимать порты с 1 до 1024

На сервере стоит Centos, под управлением ISP Manager.

Сервер

```
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://domain.com:1488/chat");
    $ws_worker->count = 1;



    // Emitted when new connection come
    $ws_worker->onConnect = function ($connection) {


        echo "Connection open {$connection->id}\n";
        $message = [
            "action" => "login",
        ];
        $connection->send(json_encode($message));

        $users = [];
        foreach ($connection->worker->connections as $client) {
            if ($client->user[0])
                $users[$client->user[0]] = $client->user[1];
        }

        $message = [
            "action" => "users",
            "data" => [
                "users" => $users
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($connection->worker->connections as $client) {
            $client->send(json_encode($message));
        }
    };



    // Run worker
    Worker::runAll();
```

Клиент самый простой

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://domain.com:1488/chat");
socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};
```

Но суть не в самом сервере или клиенте, суть в том что когда запускаю демон, почему-то нет соединения с ним. Возможно какая-то особенность в работе с портами?

***UPD***

**При работе в дебаг режиме**

**netstat -anp |grep 1488**

```
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8931/WorkerMan: mas 
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52324      ESTABLISHED 8933/WorkerMan: wor 
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52309      ESTABLISHED 8933/WorkerMan: wor
```

**При работе демона**

```
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9100/WorkerMan: mas 
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52427      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52409      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52324      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52309      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 95.246.72.147:1488      25.74.96.126:52414      TIME_WAIT   -
```

Comment: Примеры с Интернета пробовали, вот этот, например, с адаптацией под свои нужды (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850695/Пример-использования-веб-сокетов-на-php-с-workerman) ? Мало деталей, поместите минимальный код клиента и сервера.

Comment: естественно, я так и пробовал

Comment: На 10й Windows с OpenServer всё работает как нужно, вероятно какие-то настройки для centos, или же listen IP для вашего веб сервера?

Comment: Вы создаёте соединение на порту 1488 . Уверены, что в настройках сервера разрешено открывать его? Проверьте фаервол, обычно лочат все порты - оставляют доступными только внутри сервера, а открытые порты прописывают в фаерволе.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии.
Порты открывал через iptables, в дебаге же работает.

Comment: Вероятно тогда это особенности режима сервиса/daemon в PHP. Вы можете попробовать заменить это на обычный режим с поддержкой сервиса системой через systemd/ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)

Comment: Решили вопрос с запуском Workerman ? У меня такая же ситуация: в режиме дебага клиенты соединяются с сервером. Но в режиме демона ничего не работает.
Сервер на dedian

Comment: Не решилось..... @ВладимирD

Comment: Я заметил, что workerman перестает отправлять данные клиенту после строчки $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) в моем коде. Хотя ошибок нет никаких при этом. Даже предупреждений никаких нет. Просто перестает работать и всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У библиотеки специфическая работа с процессами, нельзя запускать подключение к БД до завершения запуска вебсокетов. Подключение необходимо делать внутри события onConnect.