# Мессенджер для сайта php nodejs mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

помогите с кашей в голове...
есть самописный сайт на php с MVC мне необходимо для него сделать мессенджер на nodejs. Я не знаю как сделать чтоб после авторизации через php форму у авторизованого пользователя появлялось окно чата. Подобие фейсбука. А на страницах других пользователей, если они в сети, чтоб появлялась кнопка создать чат и когда человек нажмет чтоб написать начинается собственно общение между ними с сохранением в базу.
как это можно реализовать. Я облазил кучу ресурсов и везде находил примеры и статьи чатов с комнатами только на node js с модулями но каксделать мессенджер для сайта после авторизации не понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Сам мессенджер это больше javascript программирование. Можешь посмотреть vue.js там нечто подобное очень просто реализовать.

Что касаемо реал-тайм взаимодействия. Тут однозначно тебе нужно прочитать про веб-сокеты. В php есть workerman вот тут отличный показательный пример
  [Пример использования веб-сокетов на php с workerman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850695/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-%D1%81-workerman?rq=1)

Такие приложения нужно изначально делать с заделом, на то что в них будет система реал тайм взаимодействия и делать систему событий, что бы можно было в сокеты прокидывать нужные события, которые потом уйдут на клиент.

Comment: Это достаточно сложная задача. Если с сокетами не знаком и если не знаешь как правильно выстроить архитектуру приложения хотя бы на микросервисах с евентами, то сюда можешь даже не лезть.